# How to validate string parameter with ValidationAttribute

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, http-get

how can i validate a string parameter in a HttpGet method using ValidationAttribute:

```
public class LocaleAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public LocaleAttribute() : base(UserInteractionErrors.InvalidLocale) { }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value is string && CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).Any(c => string.Equals(c.Name, (string)value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}

[ApiController]
public class ConsentController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/get/{locale}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([Locale] string locale)
    {
        something
    }
}
```

The IsValid method is not being called.
Any ideeas?

Comment: What doesn't work with the posted code?

Comment: Sorry about that, i've edited the post. The IsValid method is not being called

Comment: See [Validation attributes on action parameters](https://blog.markvincze.com/how-to-validate-action-parameters-with-dataannotation-attributes/#validationattributesonactionparameters) and [Top level parameters in ASP.NET Core 2.1](https://andrewlock.net/coming-in-asp-net-core-2-1-top-level-mvc-parameter-validation/#toplevelparametersinaspnetcore21).

Comment: I made a test with your code under `Asp.Net Core 2.1`, but fail to reproduce your issue. Do you get value for `locale` parameter? Could you share us a reproduceable project?

Comment: yes, i get a value for locale, for example if i call the endpoint with api/get/aa-aa the isValid method should return false, but the method is never being called to validate the locale.

Comment: @MarkG i've added the ValidateActionParametersAttribute class and now the IsValid Method is being called and the ModelState is invalid but it seems it is too late because the [ApiController] attribute doesn't return BadRequest

Comment: Could you share us a demo project to reproduce?